# Use of unresolved identifier using an alert.addAction

Tags: swift, alert, uialertaction

I'm getting an error on my alert.addAction(). Seems like my project doesn't know where to find it, am I right?

I made an alert without buttons, now I'm trying to add buttons to it.

So this is my alert window and the code to add the buttons:

```
func naamInModelChangedHandler ( notification:NSNotification ) {
    println("De naam in de model is veranderd naar \(model.naam!)")
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(
                self,
                name: "NAAM_CHANGED",
                object: model)

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Ola", message: "De naam is gewijzigd", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    alert.addAction(okAction)
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)

}
```

I've made a UIAlertAction with the name AlertController with some code to make the buttons.

```
let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (action) -> Void in
    println("Ok geklikt")
}
let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel) { (action) -> Void in
    println("Cancel geklikt")
}
```

But it seems it doesn't know where to look for I think. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Where do you declare your actions and your alert? Show us more please

Comment: Have you defined okAction and cancelAction before     alert.addAction(okAction)
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)?

Comment: @Amit89 I haven't declared them before it. Should I? If so, how would I do this?

Comment: @fluidsonic the error is: Use of unresolved identifier 'okAction' and 'cancelAction'

Comment: Before you execute `alert.addAction(okAction)`you have to declare and initialize `okAction`

Comment: @zellb I'll add my notificationCenter in my post, tell me if you need to see more.

Comment: yes please update your question with all your code

Comment: The `let okAction = …` and `let cancelAction = …` should occur in the `naamInModelChangedHandler` function just before `alert.addAction(okAction)`.

Comment: @fluidsonic or they should be declared as class properties

Comment: @zellb yeah that's also possible but depending on the code which goes into the closures this will cause a memory leak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do like this

```
func naamInModelChangedHandler ( notification:NSNotification ) {
    println("De naam in de model is veranderd naar \(model.naam!)")
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(
                self,
                name: "NAAM_CHANGED",
                object: model)

   let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Ola", message: "De naam is gewijzigd", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

   let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (action) -> Void in

    println("Ok geklikt")
   }

  let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel) { (action) -> Void in

    println("Cancel geklikt")
  }

    alert.addAction(okAction)
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)

}
```

Comment: Oh so I put it in the same function, not in another file. Seems like I misunderstood that part. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, need to declare before use. If it helped, you can up vote, it will help others as correct answer. :)

Comment: I cannot yet upvote as my reputation is not high enough, I marked it as correct though.